# Invariant sets under ODE defined by functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a function. I am interested in the general question of when the set $\{F(x)\geq 0\}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$
is invariant under the ODE $\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = f(x)$? For example if $\frac{d}{dt}F(x(t_0)) > 0$ whenever $F(x(t_0))=0$ then this is clearly true. However is it sufficient if we only have the weaker condition $\frac{d}{dt}F(x(t_0)) \geq 0$ whenever $F(x(t_0))=0$?

I suspect that in this case stronger conditions are needed, perhaps some kind of Lipschitz continuity. The function $y(t)=t^3$ comes to my mind where even though the derivative at $t=0$ is zero this function is not nonnegative.

The motivation for my question comes from the proofs in Proposition 6.5 and 7.6 in Brendle's *Ricci Flow and Sphere Theorem*, that various sets are invariant under the Hamilton ODE. In Proposition 6.5 where one shows the set
$$\{R\in \mathcal{C}_B(\mathbb{R}^3):\lambda_1+\lambda_2\geq 2\delta \lambda_3\}$$
is invariant under the Hamilton ODE $\frac{d}{dt}R=Q(R)$, it sufficed to show that on the boundary when $\lambda_1+\lambda_2= 2\delta \lambda_3$ we have $\frac{d}{dt}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2- 2\delta \lambda_3)\geq 0$. However in Proposition 7.6 where one shows the set
$$\{R\in \mathcal{C}_B(\mathbb{R}^3):R\text{ has nonnegative isotropric curvature}\}$$
is invariant under the Hamilton ODE $\frac{d}{dt}R=Q(R)$, an extra step was needed by perturbation of the ODE in the form of $\frac{d}{dt}R=Q(R)+\epsilon I$. A related question is why is the extra step needed in the second proof but not the first?